# .htaccess rewrite adds a directory to the url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a load of rewrite rules which map, for example /contact/ to /contact.php, /prices/ to prices.php and so on.

My problem is that when clicking the link .... - the url I get is:

```
http://173.254.28.59/~lpassodr/~lpassodr/contact/
```

Rather than:

```
http://173.254.28.59/~lpassodr/contact/
```

and thus contact.php can't be loaded because it's not in that directory.

Here's my .htacess:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*$ index.php
RewriteRule ^home/*$ index.php
RewriteRule ^contact/*$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^testimonials/*$ testimonials.php
RewriteRule ^prices/*$ prices.php
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: In case it helps, the root is `http://173.254.28.59/~lpassodr/`

Comment: Have you tried prepending `/` to the resulting pages? Say, `RewriteRule ^testimonials/*$ /testimonials.php`. As you want them from the root, make that explicit.

Comment: @desert69 Yes, but I've tried it again now to be on the safe side, still comes out the same. I think it's the way I'm connecting, via ://ip/user/ - .htaccess seems to be thinking the user is a directory, using a domain might fix it...